# Clonezilla Live log file?

Tags: clonezilla

I'm trying to restore a disk using Clonezilla, but it fails. Now I would like to read a log file, perhaps the same output that is written to stdout during installation. But I can't find such a log file.

Is there one?

If not, can I make it write to a log file, that is available afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/var/log/clonezilla.log`

During the actual clone you see a blue screen & progress, that log is here:

`/var/log/partclone.log`

Note: I was using Ultimate Boot CD v5.2.9, I was booted to Parted Magic & using clonezilla in that environment